# KingswaySoft: Nav source component filter

Tags: kingswaysoft

I can't make filter to No field (Nvarchar type). I need to filter record with diferent value at 624.
I'd tryied with  code: <>'624'
The error that show me: Detailed Message: Soap message is invalid!.Do someone help me?Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In order to provide the "not equal to" filter in NAV Source component, you could use the XML encoded values as shown below, which would translate to <>'624'.

```
&lt;&gt;'624'
```

Please give it a try and share update if there is any more issues.